# Inserting new disks into an HP Proliant DL360 G7 while running

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, hotswap

The documentation for my HP Proliant DL360 G7 says I can hot-swap phsyical disks in existing RAID sets. It doesn't say anything about inserting new physical disks and creating new logical disks while it's running. I've got one disk slot used, 3 open, and 3 disks ready to be added.*

I have the ACU utility, hpacucli, installed on Ubuntu Server. It would make sense that I can insert the disks, create new logical disks with hpacucli, format them, mount them, and use them. But I'm a newbie with HP servers and don't want to do anything dangerous. Anyone know if this is safe?

** These are consumer-grade SSDs, ADATA USA Premier SP550 960GB (I need good speed/price, not reliability). The one disk I have running right now is the same exact SSD, so I'm sure these will work in my server.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this live while the server is running.

However, I'd caution against using just any consumer SSD on the Smart Array P410 controller. Maybe specify the make/model you're using... Some incompatible SSDs will impact the temperature sensors on the drive backplane or just not work at all.

But in general, you can perform this action live, in addition to creating and configuring new logical drives.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll give it a try and report back. I've also updated my question with the exact model of the SSD.